# Update multiple table rows in a column with different values

Tags: sql

I have multiple rows i need to update and insert customer names. How can I do this in one query as opposed to running something like the below query again and again with different names?

```
UPDATE orders
SET cust_name = 'Sue'
WHERE p_id = 6
```

Comment: What database system are you using?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific how you want to update the data and from where

Comment: In other words, how are you going to supply IDs and names to the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like

```
    UPDATE mytable
    SET myfield = CASE other_field
        WHEN 1 THEN 'value'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'value'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'value'
    END
    WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

For more info check [Update Multiple Rows With Different Values and a Single SQL Query](http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-and-a-single-sql-query/)

Answer (score 0):

You generally can't. At least, MySQL, DB2, SQL Server and PostgreSQL don't support queries where different WHERE clauses apply to different SET clauses.

You also don't need to. What you usually can do is use a prepared statement with placeholders for the variables, that you execute with a list of tuples of parameters. Depending on the language, database adapter and database, this may be executed in 'batch' mode, which is quite efficient.

More precision requires more information about the language, database and database adapter you are using.